# 3D plot of monthly temperature in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, temperature

I want to plot 3D temperature distribution to demonstrate the trend of temperature according to years and months in the same graph. The x and y axes denote the month and year. The z-axis shows the hourly temperature. How to show multiple distribution to show the trend of temperature.

This is the temperature data.
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AndXEcE6b4oxeaSk0sBJrcJuJ0c?e=6DvrFG

Comment: Could you please share some data using `dput`?

Comment: I'm so sorry that I don't know how to share data using dput. I just share the data using dropbox link. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/0q2wr1gm1z2iosn97mgds/Temp2.xls?dl=0&rlkey=twxucimacrlilrmxuzkq50t7o

Answer (score 1):

If you want a rotatable 3D surface plot, then `plotly` is your best bet. You will need to first get the monthly average of temperatures and create a matrix from them.

One option for doing this is using the `tidyverse` to pivot to long format, summarize, then pivot to wide format. Here's how to do that, assuming your data frame as loaded from the csv is called `temp`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

temp %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Hour'), 
               names_to = 'Hour',
               values_to = 'Temperature') %>%
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(Temperature = mean(Temperature, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Month, values_from = Temperature) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-1) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  plot_ly(x = month.name, y = unique(temp$Year), z = .) %>%
  add_surface()
```

[image]

A nice alternative 2D way to show this kind of data would be with a heatmap:

```r
temp %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Hour'), 
               names_to = 'Hour',
               values_to = 'Temperature') %>%
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(Temperature = mean(Temperature, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, Month, fill = Temperature)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:12,
                     labels = month.name) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]